# External HD Ubuntu won't boot after changing internal HD

Tags: boot, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have a ADATA HD650 1TB external hard drive connected externally to my desktop via USB. I have ubuntu installed on it but I can't boot into it. I have tried to plug it into a different PC but same problem. What should I do next ?

Comment: You need to understand how the modern UEFI boot process works. Once you understand it then it should be easy to understand that what likely happened was the drive you removed had the EFI System Partition where Grub was installed (it always default to the internal drive's ESP even when installing in an external drive).

Comment: Be aware of bug  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379  The EFI partition on your USB disk is probably empty, no bootloaders at all.  Reinstall grub there, or maybe just copy the hard disk's EFI files to the USB's EFI.

Comment: Install Grub2 to the external EFI partition.